# How to check if a file exists after a specific interval of time

Tags: bash, shell

I want to check if a directory contains a file (for example sample.txt). If it doesn't contain that file in 5 hrs then I would need to perform some action.
How can I do this in a script?

I tried this:

```
if=$(find /home/Savio/Dsktop/check -type f -Sample.txt "*.txt") )
```

What will be the commands I need to use?

Comment: `sleep 5h; yourcommand`.

Comment: @davidbaumann this should be in answer not in comment.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the time to make a answer with explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above shell script suggested by statox is of course correct, but it does not take into account the fact the computer may go down in between the two checks, or you may logout, or you may interrupt the ssh session from which you are running the script.

The simplest way to assure yourself against all these events simultaneously is to use the *at* command to execute forward in time the second check. Thus I suggest the above script be modified as follows:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 FILE=/home/Savio/Dsktop/check/sample.txt    
 if [ -f $FILE ]
 then
        #Do what you want if file exists
 else
        at now + 5 hours /home/Savio/ExecutableScript
 fi
```

where */home/Savio/ExecutableScript* is an executable script (*chmod 755 ExecutableScript) which checks for the exitence of the file *sample.txt*, and, if it does not exist, takes suitable actions knowing that the 5h time lapse has expired already.

I understand most people are not familiar with the *at now + 5 hours* format of *at* invocation, you may find it detailed [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at).

The above will survive reboots, logouts, disconnections.

EDIT: the *at* command is especially useful because it uses **your** environment, not *root's*. Also, keep in mind that *at* uses the standard Bourne shell **sh**, not the Bourne-again shell *bash*. Thus, in the she-bang in the file /home/Savio/ExecutableScript, make sure you specify the bash shell explicitly, for it to work as you expect it to.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like that

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=/home/Savio/Dsktop/check/sample.txt    
if [ -f $FILE ]
then
    #Do what you want if file exists
else
    sleep 5h
    if [ ! -f $FILE ]
    then
        #Do what you want if the file still doesn't exists
    fi
fi
```

The variable `$FILE` contains the path of the file you are looking for, it can be modified to search for other files.

The test `if [ ! -f $FILE ]` use the `-f` parameter which is "Test if the file exists".

And the delay you need is implemented with `sleep 5h`. Sleep allows to pause a script. If you don't provide a suffix after the number the time is interpreted as seconds but you can also use the suffixes `s`, `m`, `h` and `d` to set time to seconds, minutes, hours or days.

**EDIT :** The problem of this method is that it won't survive a reboot or a disconnection, see the answer of @MariusMatutiae for a more robust solution.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on his answer so I'll do it here: The answer of @MariusMatutiae is way more robust and the use of `at now` is pretty cool I didn't know about it. OP should accept this answer.

Comment: @startox your answer is right, the user didnt ask about persistent command so your script solve his question.

Comment: @Francisco indeed my answer solve the problem but I find his solution more elegant since it covers more scenarios without introducing a drawback :) That said OP is free to use the solution she feels the more appropriate to her situation.